# Pywin32 SendKeys: "Windows button" keypress

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, pywin32

I'm trying to use Python to lock my computer. The only way I know to do this via keystrokes is by holding down the "Windows button" and pressing the "L" key. However, I can't figure out how to do this with Pywin32.

I found an extensive list of Pywin32's available keys: http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/136/254/
(But it doesn't include the "Windows button," so I'm still stuck.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a few other functions I'd like to (but don't have to) have the ability to do that require the Windows key.

Comment: I now have it where I can use the Windows key, except it doesn't work in combination with letters (but it does work with the other keys like the "right arrow"). LINK: http://pastebin.com/Ew21FASU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Tim Golden's [pages](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/lock_my_workstation.html):

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```